# Javascript: error Block-scoped in Heroku with Nodejs an Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm using node.js and express inside Heroku.

In the route file I use the `let` but I'm taking the following error:
`SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)`

**routes/app.js**

```
router.post('/auth', function(req, res, next) {
    for( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

I already put it in the file **package.json** `engines` but it still did not work

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.2.2"
 }
```

And I do not know how to use `strict mode`, in which file I put, or in what place of the file, because I already tried to put the expression `"use strict";` in many locations of file but other errors will begin to appear.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: You can *only* use `let` in strict mode. Just put `"use strict";` in the top of your code - then all code will be using strict mode.

Comment: What "other errors" are appearing when you use strict mode? Probably that's a good thing actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work `"use strict";` in Express just enter it in the top of the **app.js** file that is in the root of the project.

[image]

Comment: You'd need to do it in *every* file, e.g. `/routes/app` as well